# making a Live CD

Tags: 12.04

I am running Windows 7 Professional.  I have downloaded version 12.04 iso.  Can not find Windows iso burner as described in your web page.  Downloaded the opensorce cd/dvd burner and made disk.  Disk does not work.  Am I missing something?   When using the windows 7 it opens the iso as a compressed file and asks to unpack it. According to the web page instructions there is no mention of having to unpack.

Comment: Right click on the iso, and mouse over 'Open with...', select something along the lines of windows disc burner. If that brings up the dialog to burn a disc, there you go, if not, your installation is modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 1gb or more usb drive you can use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
If you still want to use a cd burn the "Disk Image" using [Infrarecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5)